# AWS.config.credentials.get() taking too much time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I'm using `AWS.config.crendentials.update()` to update my credentials and I want latest cognitoIdentityId so Is it necessary to call get() method of `AWS.config.crendentials` to get latest **cognitoIdentityId** because it is taking too much time, as much as 6-7 secs.

Is there any way to avoid get() call?